# "Try one's hand at something" -- why is it not hands?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

I came across this phrase today

> Try one's hand at something

Why is it not **hands** since we have a pair of hands?

In addition to that, I have also noticed both

> pleasing to the ear
>
> pleasing to the ears

are commonly used. Are both version grammatically correct?

The closest match I can find in dictionary is **music to ears** which is plural.

Comment: There is a similar phrase: "He can turn his hand to anything."

Comment: Basically, "try ones hand" is idiomatic.  "Try ones hands" is not.

Comment: @HotLicks think "try her hands", "try his hands", "try our hands" sounds idiomatic too.

Comment: @Jalene - "Dry her hands" is idiomatic.  "Try her hands" is not.

Comment: Idioms can't really be explained logically, they just happen.

Comment: Interestingly, lots of idioms in which the 'hand' occurs seem to be singular: 'talk to the hand', 'overplay your hand', 'out of hand', 'to ask the hand'. I wonder if this has something to do with its etymology?